# Invoke Delegate (Method)

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke

I got some code that uses a delegate to pass the percentage of the operation.
But the delegate method is run on the same thread as the operation, which is a backgroundworker. So updating a progressbar in the delegate method is impossible without invocation.

Should I just invoke in the delegate method or is there a better way?
I didn't really understand the example that is on msdn (it was in vb.net too which made it harder :/).

Comment: Put some code, and link to that secret MSDN page you are mentioning.

Comment: If you are indeed using a `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` then all you need to do is call `ReportProgress(int)` and handle the `ProgressChanged` event.  Excellent example, in C#, on MSDN already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: @zmilojko Can't find the page, I found it on my laptop earlier today. I wrote this question in a hurry, so forgive me if I didn't post any code.

Comment: @harlam357 Well that was clever. Didn't thought of it since I didn't do all of this directly in the DoWork method, but in a sub-method. But of course you can call the ReportProgress anywhere as long as it is on that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add something along the lines of the below to the form containing the progress bar.
This will check to see if an invoke is required.

```
public void SetProgressValue(int value)
{
    if (this.ProgressBar.InvokeRequired)
    {
       this.BeginInvoke(new Action<int>(SetProgressValue), value);
       return;
    }
    this.ProgressBar.Value= value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)() => YourDelegate());

Comment: Where was it mentioned it is for Windows Forms?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mentioned it. But it is windows forms it is all about (Wouldn't use a background worker if it were a console)

Comment: Well then 53AN's answer looks right (though probably does not need the "<int>" specified explicitly). It looks almost identical in Silverlight and WPF except they have Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and Dispatcher.CheckAccess(), while WinForms seems to have control.BeginInvoke and control.InvokeRequired...